# how to stream video files on Node.js web app efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, video-streaming, filereader

I'm trying to build a video screening room app using node.JS, Javascript, HTML, CSS.
I'm not clear on how to implement it using FileReader or MediaStream APIs available for the browser.
The concept is like anyone can select a video file available on their local machine and I want to stream that file to all the participants available in the room connected through socket.io. At the moment I'm at a very basic level of this functionality where I'm reading a video file selected, using FileReader. And I read that file whole and convert it to blob and send it to my node.js server by emitting an event.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
                
            reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

                var blob = new Blob([event.target.result], {
                    type: mime
                  })

                socket.emit('buffering',{ mediaBuffer: blob },(data)=>{
                    console.log("buffering called once")
                })

            });
 
            
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile);
```

now, when the event reaches the server it passes on this buffered blob data to all participants in the room using socket.

```
socket.on('buffering',({mediaBuffer},callback)=>{

        const user = getUser(socket.id)
        io.to(user.room).emit('bufferingData',mediaBuffer)
    })
```

and now for the other participants, I'm creating a video element on an event when received from the server. After the element is created, when the server starts emitting buffer data through socket I receive that data convert it to blob again, and create an ObjectURL to read data from it.

```
socket.on("startStreamingPlayer",()=>{

    const html = Mustache.render($videotemp, {
        videoDiv:'<video id="draggable"  controls> <source src="" type="video/mp4"></video>'
    })

   $messages.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)

let videoElement = document.getElementById('draggable');

 socket.on('bufferingData', (bufferData) => {
    

    console.log("buffering data")
    var blob = new Blob([bufferData], {
        type: "video/mp4"
      })

   const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

   videoElement.src = url;

   videoElement.play();

    console.log("buffering data");

})

})
```

This is a very basic version I could put together but, I'm trying to find some other efficient method to achieve this. where I could break down large video files in chunks of data and have it flow through sockets and buffer them on clients and play the video on clients without putting a load on the network, cache, or CPU.

Can anyone please suggest to me some way to achieve this?

Comment: Are all the clients to stay in-sync with each other?  Does latency matter?  You could do this with WebRTC if so.  Otherwise, why not just use WebTorrent?

Comment: yes, all have to be in sync, the one who starts the streaming should be in control. If you know how to achieve this, can you please guide me to the reference? @Brad